# Can't insert data in database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to insert a color code selected by the user into my database, but it doesn't seem to work.

For example, if I select cookware, then it should insert `#A8CF45` into the database, if I select dinner, then it should insert `#EDCA86`.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

Here is the HTML:

```
<select class="col-sm-9" id="cate" name="cate">
    <option value="cookware">Cookware</option>
    <option value="dinner">Dinner Set</option>
    <option value="tiffin">Tiffin</option>
    <option value="storage">Storage</option>
</select>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
<?php

$cate=$_POST["cate"];

if('cookware' == $cate){
    $bg_color= '#A8CF45';
}
elseif('dinner' == $cate){
    $bg_color= '#EDCA86';
}
elseif('tiffin' == $cate){
    $bg_color= '#FBB12F';
}
elseif('storage' == $cate){
    $bg_color= '#F26F35';
}
else{
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO table( bg_color) VALUES ('$bg_color')")or die("Could not retrieve image: " .mysqli_error($conn));
    echo 1;
}   
?>
```

Comment: Why is your query in the `else` statement? That's probably not what you want.

Comment: How does it fail? Have you created the connection?
You need to learn about SQL injection. The style of the code where you include the value as part of a string for the query is a significant security risk in most real environments. Find out about how to paramaterise queries instead.

Comment: @explv: You did edit the question after I did edit it and you did include my corrections too. Now I‘m blocked and can‘t edit or do any further improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should like

```
<?php

$cate=$_POST["cate"];

if('cookware' == $cate){
    $bg_color= '#A8CF45';
}
elseif('dinner' == $cate){
    $bg_color= '#EDCA86';
}
elseif('tiffin' == $cate){
    $bg_color= '#FBB12F';
}
elseif('storage' == $cate){
    $bg_color= '#F26F35';
} 
if(!empty($bg_color)) {
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO table( bg_color) VALUES ('$bg_color')")or die("Could not retrieve image: " .mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your query out of last `else`.

Here is the updated code snippet:

```
<?php

$cate=$_POST["cate"];

if('cookware' == $cate){
    $bg_color= '#A8CF45';
}
elseif('dinner' == $cate){
    $bg_color= '#EDCA86';
}
elseif('tiffin' == $cate){
    $bg_color= '#FBB12F';
}
elseif('storage' == $cate){
    $bg_color= '#F26F35';
}
if(isset($bg_color) && !empty($bg_color)){
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO table( bg_color) VALUES ('$bg_color')")or die("Could not retrieve image: " .mysqli_error($conn));
    echo '1';// Changed 1 as a string.
   }
?>
```